# Lateral balance of single aisle planes with odd numbers of seats in each row

Tags: aircraft-design

Do single aisle passenger planes with an expected odd number of seats in each row (e.g. 2-3, 1-2) where the aisle ends up not being central adjust the design of the plane overall to account for this and if so, how?  If the plane later gets deployed in a cargo capacity does much need altering based on the above?

Answer (score 4):

In a 1 - 2 seating config, with a full aircraft, the off center weighting of the PAX is not that far off the absolute centerline. Maybe 18". Easily handled by trim settings.

Comment: In all of my years of flying only once did I experience a flight attendant asking some passengers to move for weight and balance reasons. It was a commuter turboprop, probably about 35 passenger size, but there were less than ten of us on the flight. Naturally everyone had selected seats near the front. The FA asked for a few volunteers to move to either the middle or rear of the plane. To your point she said nothing about what side of the aisle to sit on.

Comment: @StevePemberton the distances are quite different in the longitudinal axis.

Comment: I've experienced that in 737s (again longitudinal rather than lateral). The flight had something like 10-20 passengers total.

Comment: @jcaron - "_the distances are quite different in the longitudinal axis."_ Would you mind elaborating on that? ROFL